# changing value of ion-input from external js file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on a project (Ionic3, Angular5).

I tried to change the value of ion-input from outside js file imported in root index file with no chance.

```
<ion-input (ngModelChange)="valueChange($this)" [(ngModel)]="name" id="dataIn"></ion-input>
```

using

```
document.getElementById("data").value = somedata;
```

and

```
document.getElementById('data').setAttribute("value", somedata);
```

Any help.

Comment: The id in the html is dataIn :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the source you can notice that `<ion-input>` is actually just a wrapper, not the real input field which is a direct child.

So you can do it this way :

```
document.getQuerySelector("#dataIn > input").value = somedata;
```